# php array unable to convert to json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using ajax request to fetch records from database convert to json and return response, I'm getting it to success part of ajax and then appending it to html table.
Now the problem is some of the rows from db is showing as unidentified characters. I print the variable before converting to json and I see this 15th key in array

```
  [15] => Array
    (
        [UserDetail] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => TEST
                [last_name] => ABC
            )

        [Client] => Array
            (
                [title] => Më-XÝv
                [address] => 
                [contactno] => 
                [city] => Edison
                [profile_pic] => 8467_logo.png
            )
    )
```

Now see the title key in Client array, its showing some random character thats why the array is unable to convert to json. How can I resolve this issue and convert array in to json.
Please help.

Comment: Are you using json_encode function?

Comment: set charset in your query $conn->set_charset("utf8");

Comment: @lalithkumar Yes I'm using json encode echo json_encode($ret);

Comment: WHY downvoted ..please explain

Comment: $myArray= Array
    (
        'UserDetail' => Array
            (
                'first_name' => 'TEST',
                'last_name' => 'ABC',
            ),

        'Client' => Array
            (
                'title' => 'Më-XÝv',
                'address' =>'',
                'contactno' =>'',
                'city' => 'Edison',
                'profile_pic' => '8467_logo.png',
            ),
    );

Comment: Create array like above ...It will work like charm

Comment: Array is proper because its a printed array.

Comment: @Aamir I haven't down voted you, but I suspect whoever did was because you haven't shown your code in your question. Edit your question to show what you are doing and what it is returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out issue, the title names are stored as encrypted in the table, and on fetching records it is decrypting the title value, now in that row title name was in plain text so it was decrypting plain text in to unreadable characters. Hence it was unable to convert to json.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.hope this will help.

```
$myArray= Array
        (
            'UserDetail' => Array
                (
                    'first_name' => 'TEST',
                    'last_name' => 'ABC',
                ),

            'Client' => Array
                (
                    'title' => 'Më-XÝv',
                    'address' =>'',
                    'contactno' =>'',
                    'city' => 'Edison',
                    'profile_pic' => '8467_logo.png',
                ),
        );
```